# Video overlay issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, safari

I'd like to create a `video` overlay. It works great in Chrome with https://stackoverflow.com/a/30310041/8254123, but has some issues in Safari. When I add `controls` to the `video` tag and want to pause the video, Safari returns this error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: [object DOMError]

If I remove the `controls` attribute it works, but I need `controls` and don't want to add custom `controls`.

```js
jQuery('.video_home_1').click(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).children("video").get(0).paused) {
    jQuery(this).children("video").get(0).play();
    jQuery(this).find(".playpause").fadeOut();
    jQuery(this).find(".home_video_overlay").fadeOut();
  } else {
    jQuery(this).children("video").get(0).pause();
    jQuery(this).find(".playpause").fadeIn();
    jQuery(this).find(".home_video_overlay").fadeIn();
    jQuery(this).children(".home_video_overlay").css('background', 'transparent');
  }
});
```

```css
.video_home_1 {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 425px;
}

.video_home_1 .playpause {
  background: url(https://www.squaresigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/play.png) 58% 50% no-repeat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  background-size: 64px 64px;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.video_home_1 .home_video_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 425px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.video_home_1 video {
  height: 425px;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="video_home_1">
  <video controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.squaresigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/SquareSigns.mp4">
    <source type="video/webm" src="https://www.squaresigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/SquareSigns.webm">
  </video>
  <div class="home_video_overlay" style="background-image: url('https://www.squaresigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cover.png');">
    <div class="playpause"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it with this js code

```
jQuery('.video_home_1').attr("played","no");
    jQuery('.video_home_1').click(function () {
        if(jQuery(this).attr('played')=="no"){
            jQuery(this).attr("played","yes");
            jQuery(this).children("video").get(0).play();
            jQuery(this).find(".playpause").fadeOut();
            jQuery(this).find(".home_video_overlay").fadeOut();
            jQuery(this).children("video").css("z-index","99");
        }else{
            jQuery(this).attr("played","no");
            jQuery(this).children("video").get(0).pause();
            jQuery(this).find(".playpause").fadeIn();
            jQuery(this).find(".home_video_overlay").fadeIn();
            jQuery(this).children(".home_video_overlay").css('background', 'transparent');
            jQuery(this).children("video").css("z-index","1");
        }
}   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ditch jquery and do a pure javascript implementation?

Or have seperate logic that has a more fluid use in javascript. for which browser type.

:)

Hope you figure it out I'd look at the video api through mozilla
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    var playButton = document.getElementsByClassName("video_home_1");
    playButton[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (video[0].paused == true) {
        // Play the video
        video[0].play();

      } else {
        // Pause the video
        video[0].pause();

      }
    });
 Thanks for answer. But have done with pure javascript and same result.

Comment: what is zero index of document.getElementsByTagName("video");
:D

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set `controls="true"` as in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad)

```
<div class="video_home_1">
  <video controls="true">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.squaresigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/SquareSigns.mp4">
    <source type="video/webm" src="https://www.squaresigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/SquareSigns.webm">
  </video>
  <div class="home_video_overlay" style="background-image: url('https://www.squaresigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cover.png');">
    <div class="playpause"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't need to add true to controls, if controls exist it's mean it true and must show control buttons. And it not solve the problem.